# Target div and previous titles with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML structure like this, and would like to move all the image galleries together with their corresponding titles and subtitles to a different position `.image_content`

```
<h2>Some section</h2>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>

<h2>Some other section</h2>
<h3>Some sub-section</h3>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>

<h2>Planos</h2>
<div id='gallery-4' class='gallery'>
    <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
    <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
    <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
    <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
</div>

<h2>Fotos</h2>
<h3>Fotos archivo</h3>
<div id='gallery-5' class='gallery'>
    <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
    <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
    <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
    <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
</div>
```

So far I've got this code to move the galleries:

```
$('.gallery').appendTo('.image_content');
```

But I'm failing to also get the corresponding H2 and H3 titles. I've tried this but it's not working:

```
$('.gallery').prev('h2').appendTo('.image_content'); 
$('.gallery').appendTo('.image_content');
```

This is the expected result (`image_content` already exists in another part of the code):

```
<div class="image_content">
    <h2>Planos</h2>
    <div id='gallery-4' class='gallery'>
        <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
        <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
        <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
        <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
    </div>

    <h2>Fotos</h2>
    <h3>Fotos archivo</h3>
    <div id='gallery-5' class='gallery'>
        <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
        <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
        <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
        <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this is where `.add()` should help.

Comment: @Twisty I still need to be able to target that particular H2 and H3 to work with .add(). If I'm not mistaken

Comment: Also `$(".gallery")` is ambiguous, since there are more than one in that class.

Comment: What are expected results? Also how is this html generated?

Comment: @Twisty am indeed targeting all divs with class `.gallery`

Comment: @charlietfl just edited my question to add the expected result. The HTML structure is generated by WordPress. Those are WordPress image galleries

Comment: *"Those are WordPress image galleries"* ....  fix the wordpress template. I rather doubt there are no classes or other identifiers or even wrappers on any of these elements.

Comment: Even adding a simple wrapper around each of these in the template would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.prev()` only selects the previous element. So on the second gallery it would try to select the `h2`, but it won't because it is it is a `h3`. You can use `.prevAll()` in conjunction with the `:first` to select the first element it finds, because `.prevAll()` selects all previous sibling elements of the specified selector. I didn't use `.prevAll()` for the h3 selector because on the first gallery it would select the title "Some sub-section". I also added .each() to iterate through each gallery, so you could potentially add conditional statements to use different selectors methods.

It is not the best code in the world, but it should suit your purposes, or at least a good starting point.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.gallery').each(function() {
    $(this).prevAll('h2:first').appendTo('.image_content');
    $(this).prev('h3').appendTo('.image_content');
    $(this).appendTo('.image_content');
  });
});
```

```html
 <h2>Some section</h2>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>

<h2>Some other section</h2>
<h3>Some sub-section</h3>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>

<h2>Planos</h2>
<div id='gallery-4' class='gallery'>
  <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
  <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
  <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
  <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
</div>

<h2>Fotos</h2>
<h3>Fotos archivo</h3>
<div id='gallery-5' class='gallery'>
  <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
  <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
  <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
  <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
</div>

<div class="image_content"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

EDIT: If you are not able to add a wrapper to each gallery and title then the below code with work in the situations you have described. I have added a couple of conditional statements to check if the previous `h2` or `h3` exists and if it doesn't then use `.prev().prev('h2')` and `.prev().prev('h3')`. This will select an sibling element 2 steps back.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.gallery').each(function() {
    var prevH2 = $(this).prev('h2');
    var prevH3 = $(this).prev('h3');
    if(prevH2.length == 0) {
      prevH2 = $(this).prev().prev('h2');
    }
    if(prevH3.length == 0) {
      prevH3 = $(this).prev().prev('h3').appendTo('.image_content');
    }
    prevH2.appendTo('.image_content')
    prevH3.appendTo('.image_content')
    $(this).appendTo('.image_content');
  });
});
```

```html
<h2>Some section</h2>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>

<h2>Some other section</h2>
<h3>Some sub-section</h3>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>

<h2>Planos</h2>
<div id='gallery-4' class='gallery'>
 <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
 <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
 <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
 <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
</div>

<h2>Fotos</h2>
<h3>Fotos archivo</h3>
<div id='gallery-5' class='gallery'>
 <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
 <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
 <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
 <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
</div>

<h3>Fotos archivo</h3>
<div id='gallery-5' class='gallery'>
 <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
 <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
 <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
 <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
</div>

<div class="image_content"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @WizardCoder ! This works great! Unfortunately, in trying to simplify things for the purpose of asking this question I missed to provide one particular scenario for which your code (otherwise perfect) is failing. That is if you have `h2` then `h3` then `.gallery` and then again `h3` and `.gallery`. Do you see any way around that scenario?

Comment: You could add a wrapper div around each gallery and relevent title/s. That would make this a lot simpler.

Comment: I have edited my answer if you are unable to change the HTML.

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you so much :) I've been reading the function you wrote and it makes a lot of sense now that I see it working, thank you for helping out

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the html structure you can also add an enclosing tag to the galleries:

```
<h2>Some section</h2>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>

<h2>Some other section</h2>
<h3>Some sub-section</h3>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<div>
  <h2>Planos</h2>
  <div id='gallery-4' class='gallery'>
      <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
      <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
      <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
      <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <h2>Fotos</h2>
  <h3>Fotos archivo</h3>
  <div id='gallery-5' class='gallery'>
      <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
      <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
      <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
      <dl class='gallery-item'></dl>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which simplifies your addition:

```
$(".gallery").parent().children().appendTo(".image_content");
```

It's important to note that this solution works if you only have the titles between the enclosing tags and the galleries